# Getting a Parameters Error for OAuth2

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm pretty new to this and am struggling at the moment to get an OAuth 2.0 token for use with Google Apps Script to write to a Fusion Table. I'm using the Google Developers Live code from Arun and I can't seem to get the access token. When I run the doGet function below, it gives me a "Type Error: cannot read property "parameters" from undefined".

```
function doGet(e) {
    var HTMLToOutput;
    if(e.parameters.code){//if we get "code" as a parameter in, then this is a callback. we can make this more explicit
    getAndStoreAccessToken(e.parameters.code);
    HTMLToOutput = '<html><h1>Finished with oAuth</h1>You can close this window.</html>';
    }
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLToOutput);
 }

function getAndStoreAccessToken(code){
    var parameters = {
    method : 'post',
    payload : 'client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET+'&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URL+'&code=' + code
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(TOKEN_URL,parameters).getContentText();   
  var tokenResponse = JSON.parse(response);

  // store the token for later retrieval
  UserProperties.setProperty(tokenPropertyName, tokenResponse.access_token);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Appsscript there are some triggers, these triggers execute a piece of code in response to certain action or parameters.

In this case you are using the trigger doGet (which is the name of your function). As you can see, that function receives the parameter "e". If you run that function directly in the environment, this parameter will be "undefined" as you are not passing anything to the function.

This trigger is executed when you access your code as a web application. To do this you have to click on the icon next to the "save" button (the one that looks like a cloud with an arrow) [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) you can find the information.

When you access your code through the url you obtained after deploying your app, the function receives the necessary parameter (inside "e") and then it should work.